# Ruby regular expression match precedence

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I modify the following regular expression to stop the first match section from grabbing the second? I'm using Ruby 1.9.2 if that makes a difference.

```
/\Aasync_([a-zA-Z]\w*)(_at|_in)?\z/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the [`*` quantifier lazy](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html):

```
/\Aasync_([a-zA-Z]\w*?)(_at|_in)?\z/
```

`\w*?` means "match any number of alphanumeric characters, but try to match as few as possible while still allowing the overall regex to match".